# Add a character each x characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, character

I would like to break a long word in my Ruby on Rails string (something like `<wbr>` in HTML).

Is it possible to tell Ruby to add character `x` in string `y` each `z` characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
result = subject.gsub(/(.{10})/m, '\1XX')
```

substituting the number you want for `10` and the replacement string you want for `XX`

Answer (score 1):

In Perl it would be somewhere along the lines of `s/(\w{42})/$1\n/g`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with rails, but in pure ruby you can always write your own.  No idea the amount of speed you give up for something like this if any.

```
def addcharacter(num, char, string)
 x = 0
 resultstring = ""
 string.each_byte do |byte|
   resultstring << byte.chr
   x += 1
   if x == num
   resultstring << char
   x = 0
   end

 end

   return resultstring
 end

 mystring = "hello there"

 a = addcharacter(2,"*",mystring)
 puts a
```

Comment: Careful using `each_byte` for something like this. It only works when the characters are bytes i.e. ASCII. Weird behavior would ensue with UTF-* encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

If your original string is `str = "0123456789abcde"` and you want:

- `01234XXX56789XXXabcdeXXX` :: use `str.gsub(/.{5}/, '\&XXX')`
- `01234XXX56789XXXabcde` :: use `str.scan(/.{5}/).join('XXX')`

These will produce slightly different input for `str = "012345678abcdef"`

- `01234XXX56789XXXabcdeXXXf` :: from `str.gsub(/.{5}/, '\&XXX')`
- `01234XXX56789XXXabcde` :: from `str.scan(/.{5}/).join('XXX')`
- `01234XXX56789XXXabcdeXXXfXXX` :: from `str.gsub(/.{1,5}/, '\&XXX')`
- `01234XXX56789XXXabcdeXXXf` :: from `str.scan(/.{1,5}/).join('XXX')`

Answer (score 0):

One can use a regular expression without a back-reference.

Let's add `'XX`' to `'My dog has fleas'` every `n = 3` characters:

```
'My dog has fleas'.gsub(/.{#{n}}\K/, 'XX')
  #=> "My XXdogXX haXXs fXXleaXXs"
```

The regular expression reads, "match n characters and then (`\K`) discard all previous matches and reset the regex's string pointer to the current location (just after those n characters and before the next character)".

For the example given the string pointer is initially at the beginning of the string. `.{3}` matches the first three characters of the string, `'My '`. `\K` discards that match and resets the string pointer to the (zero-width) location between the third and fourth characters, `' '` and `'d'`. `gsub` replaces that zero-width match with `'XX'` and the string pointer remains before `'d'`. The next match is `'dog'`, `\K` discards that match and resets the string pointer, the zero-width location between `'g'` and `' '`, which is replaced with `'XX'` and so on.